# Is there a way to loop execute a method while passing a different instance of a class to it each time?

Tags: java

My current code looks something like this:

```
public void myMethod()
{
   instance1.myPanel.setVisible();
   instance2.myPanel.setVisible();
   instance3.myPanel.setVisible();
   instance4.myPanel.setVisible();
   //A bunch more
   instance57.myPanel.setVisible();  
}
```

Is there a ways to shorten it?
The Code below obviously doesn't work but gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
public void myMethod2(myClass instance1)
{
   instance1.myPanel.setVisible();
}

int i = 1;
while(i <= 57)
{
   myMethod2("instance" + i);
   i++
}
```

Comment: Use an array of `myClass`es instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, this kind of problem is normally handled using some sort of collection, and its use will often fit naturally into the initialization of a program with a large number of objects. Rather than hand-writing the creation of 57 similar objects, one line at a time, you would create them in a loop, adding them to a collection as you do so.

A [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation like [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) would be a good choice here, or one could simply use an array.

With a `List`:

```java
/* During initialization of your program somewhere. */
List<MyClass> instances = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 57; ++i) {
  instances.add(new MyClass());
}

...

/* Later when you need to invoke a method: */
instances.forEach(instance -> instance.myPanel.setVisible());
```

Comment: Thank you, the list worked well, I ended up do something like this                        `int i = 0;
         while(i <= 56)
         {
            list.get(i).myMethod();
            i++;
         }`

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list of your vars and just go through them:

```java
List<ClassType> list = Arrays.asList( obj1, ob2, obj3 );
list.forEach( instance -> instance.myPanel.setVisible() );
```

Comment: You shouldn't create a `Stream` just for calling `forEach` on it right away. `Collection` also has the `forEach`, and creating streams and spliterators is taxing on performance enough that it becomes noticeable.

Comment: In modern Java you can write `List.of(...)` instead of `Arrays.asList(...)`.

Comment: thanks for the tips and thanks for @erickson for the edit